# Authorization using firebase token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, firebase-authentication, authorization

I'm using firebase authentication in react and an express js server to save the user credential. How can i manage roles (authorization) ?

I do send in each request the firebase token to be verified in the backend.

I don't know if should I add another token to decode the role on it.

Comment: use firebase-admin,
this will help you [https://medium.com/litslink/firebase-admin-sdk-basics-in-examples-ee7e009a1116](https://medium.com/litslink/firebase-admin-sdk-basics-in-examples-ee7e009a1116)

Comment: The Firebase documentation also has a page about using custom claims to control access, which seems to be exactly what you want: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 0):

If a use has a single role or an otherwise limited set of so-called claims you want to track, you can add them to their Firebase Authentication profile as so-called custom claims.

For more on this, and to learn how to use custom claims to control access, see the Firebase documentation on [controlling access with custom claims and security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).